# Choosing a random value from an array gives undefined

Tags: javascript

When I Input the first number to be for example 5 and the second Number to be like 10 I get undefined. I tried `alert(array);` to see the contents of it but there was nothing and hence undefined. It works for other numbers like 1 to 9. Why does it give me an undefined value from range 5 to 10? I just want to make a random number chooser where you will input the first number and the second number and a random number will be given to you?

```js
function promptUser() {
  var first = prompt("First number?");
  var second = prompt("Second number?");
  var array = [];
  //Make a range from First number to last number then choose a random number
  for (x = first; x <= second; x++) {
    array.push(x);
  }
  alert(array);
  randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  alert("The random number is " + array[randomInt]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns the result in *string* literal, you need to use `parseInt()` or other methods to convert *string* to *Number*.

```js
var first = parseInt(prompt("First number?"), 10);
var second = parseInt(prompt("Second number?"), 10);
var array = [];

for (x = first; x <= second; x++) {
  array.push(x);
}

randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
console.log(array, randomInt, "The random number is " + array[randomInt]);
```

Additionally, `alert()` is not a debugging tool, Learn to use [Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console)

Answer (score 0):

your first number is being treated as string needed to be parsed as int

```
function promptUser(){
    var first = prompt("First number?");
    var second = prompt("Second number?");
    var array = [];
    <!--Make a range from First number to last number then choose a random number-->
    for (x = parseInt(first); x <= parseInt(second); x++){
         array.push(x);
    }
    console.log(array);
    randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
    console.log(randomInt);
    alert("The random number is " + array[randomInt]);

    }
    promptUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var first = parseInt(prompt("First number?"));
var second = parseInt(prompt("Second number?"));
```

instead of:

```
var first = prompt("First number?");
var second = prompt("Second number?");
```

`prompt` returns `string`